# Only pattern matching string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file which contains words

```
abciuf.com abdbhj.co.in abcshjkl.org.in.2 abciuf zasdg cbhjk asjk
```

including other contents. The word starts with `abci, abdb, abcs, abai`  is my requirement. So I want only the word which print starts with `abci, abdb, abcs, abai`  like - `abciuf.com  abdbhj.co.in  abcshjkl.org.in.2   abciuf  Azerbaijan`

I have tried via grep command but it doesn't help me

```
cat /etc/xyz.txt|egrep -o "abdb*|abci*|abcs*|abai*"
cat /etc/xyz.txt|egrep -Eow "abdb*|abci*|abcs*|abai*"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Eo `\<(abdb|abci|abcs|abai)\S*' </etc/xyz.txt
```

- `\<` (or `\b`) matches start of "word" (or a "word" boundary)
- `(A|B)` matches A or B
- `\S*` matches zero or more nonspace characters (until a non-nonspace character)
- it was a good idea to try using grep's `-w` option but its definition of "word" is too strict (matching stops if it encounters `.`)
- shell meaning of `*` is not same as grep's
- you can make the regexp shorter but it becomes harder to read

Comment: @Sin15, as mentioned previously in other post too, give it sometime and when you have enough answers to your question try to select anyone of them as correct one and that will be best thanks to anyone on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl also

```
 perl -ne ' while(/(\b(abdb|abci|abcs|abai)\S+)/g) { print "$1 \n" } '
```

with your inputs

```
$ cat sin15.txt
abciuf.com abdbhj.co.in abcshjkl.org.in.2 abciuf zasdg cbhjk asjk

$ perl -ne ' while(/(\b(abdb|abci|abcs|abai)\S+)/g) { print "$1 \n" } ' sin15.txt
abciuf.com
abdbhj.co.in
abcshjkl.org.in.2
abciuf

$
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<(abdb|abci|abcs|abai)\\S*' 'RT{print RT}' file
abciuf.com
abdbhj.co.in
abcshjkl.org.in.2
abciuf
```