# Print the characters from string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file which contains words-
abfiuf.com abdbhj.co.in abcahjkl.org.in.2 abciuf zasdg cbhjk asjk

including other contents. My Requirement is -The word which starts with abfiuf,

```
abdbhj, abcahjkl, abciuf ,.... cut the two character from middle like below.
abfiuf - fi
abdbhj - db
abjcahjkl - ca
abciuf - ci
```

I have tried below-
First to get the matching word-

```
cat /etc/xyz.txt|grep -Eo \<(abfiuf|abdbhj|abjcahjkl|abciuf)\S*'|cut -f1 -d"."
```

But unable to cut before and after matching "fi" , "db" , "ca" , "ci" from words .

Tried with sed command -  `sed 's/^.*fi/fi/'` -> working only for one word removing before. But How to cut multiple char before & after from words ?

Comment: Try piping `sed 's/^..\(..\).*/& - \1/'`. See [the demo](https://ideone.com/I6r9Py). If you need just the 2 chars, [remove `& -` from the replacement pattern](https://ideone.com/Cl6u2v).

Comment: @Sin15 by seeing your profile came to know that you never select an answer as correct one. Give it sometime and when you see few answers to your question try to select any of them as correct them too. You could that for your previous question too now.

Comment: Is there any way to cut before and after the matching char "fi" , "db" , "ca" , "ci" from words ?

Comment: You got multiple answers to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54642872/1745001) on the same topic and yet here you are trying to build on the one answer that used a tool you cannot expand with to solve your next phase of problem. Really **think** about what it is you need to do and the capabilities of the available tools. Also google UUOC. Most importantly - clarify if you're trying to print those exact 2-char strings or just trying to print the middle 2 chars from each word.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT2:*** Since OP told he/she only want to print matching strings value only if that is the case then one should try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/fi|db|ca|ci/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

OR in case you want to print a message with line number that DO NOT have any match found then try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/fi|db|ca|ci/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);next} {print "Line number " FNR " is NOT having any matching value in it."}' Input_file
```

---

---

Assuming that you need to print only 3rd and 4th character if that is the case then try following.

```
awk '{print substr($0,3,2)}' Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Now I am assuming that you DO NOT want to hard code the position to print from lines if that is the case then try following, which will first calculate the length of line and will print 2 characters starting from its middle letter.

```
awk '{len=length($0)/2;print substr($0,len,2)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Sorry @Ravinder, positions of character are not fixed. My required is just to get "fi" , "db" , "ca" , "ci" from words

Comment: @Sin15, yes got it but what is the logic behind it to get it? Is my 2nd/EDIT solution working for you? Where I am taking line'e length and printing it from mid of its length.

Comment: @Sin15, please try my EDIT2 solution now and let me know? It will only print those lines which have any of the string `db` or `fi`, `ca`,`ci`.

Comment: Thank you, Its working and fulfill my need. Appreciate you veere.

Comment: @Sin15, np, give it sometime and when you have few answers try to select an answer as correct one too,cheers and happy learning.